# EclipseLink fix not available in Eclipse - Jersey POST/PUT not working

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipselink, glassfish-4

I am using Eclipse Luna (versions 4.4.2) and Glassfish 4 to build a REST web-app using JAX-RS.

All POST and PUT operations, which were previously working fine, are now throwing this error on the webserver:

```
Warning: StandardWrapperValve[Jersey Web Application]: Servlet.service() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException not found by org.eclipse.persistence.moxy
```

I have found out (in the comments here: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2888) that it has been fixed in EclipseLink 2.6.1 and Jersey 2.19.

I have updated to Jersey 2.22.1.

Eclipselink 2.6.1 has been released on Oct 15th 2015, as you can see here: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/releases/

However, as you can see here, it doesn't seem to have been incorporated into eclipse for "help -> update software": http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/updates/

Does anybody know how to get 2.6.1 working with Eclipse? At the moment, it is preventing me from completing my application, and this problem I've had for 4 weeks.

Or is there another way to fix it?

All help much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

File a bug report at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink indicating that it's neither in the main repository nor downloadable as a P2 repository on its own.